# IOS facebook get notification

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa, push-notification

I am developing an iOS application where I want to get notified as soon as a notification comes in my facebook account.

I am able to pull the notification using JSON, where I am polling every 5 minutes.

Can I get automatically something like Push-Notification, not Pull-Notification.

Not a push notification from facebook to my app, but any means by which I can perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

You will not receive any push notifications from Facebook. Facebook will only send push notification to their own app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Facebook's [notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/), but it looks like there might be a way to get a given [user's notifications](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.get/) (with some restrictions).

Once you are able to pull a Facebook notification using your server, then you would want, again using your own server, to send the push notification to a user's mobile device using [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

This might require quite a bit of backend work to make functional, or you could use something like Parse or Urban Airship. But first I would read up on [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) and how push notifications are sent to a mobile device.